# How to comparing dates from different timezones

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api

From Facebook Graph API I retrieve events which have the start_time set as string with the following format: "2012-10-12T23:30:00+0200". When location is specified it returns also the event object contains also the timezone (e.g.: "Europe/Rome").
I simply would like to check which events are upcoming (newer than "now").

I wonder if there is a way to do so without using pytz, which is not installed by default in Django. For deployment, the more portable the solution is the better.

Comment: As a side note, pytz is strongly recommended in the Django docs ([here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#setup) and throughout that page). It's also a fairly painless dependency, supporting back to python 2.4 and available on PyPI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in datetime module after a quick parse of the returned string (using "-", "T", and "+" as tokens).

Here is a quick reference to the documentation : http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

Note : this module handles timezone (search for tzone in the page).

Comment: If I use "+" as token it means that the datetime doesn't factor the timezone, does it? I don't even know how I would define in the date_string the following 4 digits :)